# Could you send the datasheet within this week

Tags: prepositional-phrases, phrase-choice, time, politeness

First I need to know if the following sentence is natural or I have to change it?

> Could you send the datasheet within this week?

If it's natural I need to know whether that is the same as the following or not:

> Could you send the datasheet by the end of this week?

Do they mean the same? Do they differ in politeness degree?

Comment: Note that "within this unit of time" is not as common in American English as in British English, and may be misinterpreted as "within a unit of time".  (within this month = by the end of this month; within a month = before ~30  days passes)

Comment: "Within this week" does not sound at all natural to me. I would either say "can you send it (by the end of) this week" or "can you send it within a week", the latter meaning the person has seven days to send it and either way of writing the former meaning that they have until Friday.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some empirical results.

[Corpus Of Contemporary American English](http://corpus2.byu.edu/coca/):

- WITHIN THIS WEEK: 2 hits
- BY THE END OF THIS WEEK: 58 hits

[BYU-BNC: British National Corpus](http://corpus2.byu.edu/coca/):

- WITHIN THIS WEEK: 0 hits
- BY THE END OF THIS WEEK: 7 hits

We can conclude from that that "by the end of the week" is much more common in both American and British English, and thus it is also probably much more natural.

Answer (score 0):

I think the meaning is about the same.

> Could you send the datasheet within this week?

is a bit indirect, so if you are not being blunt or to the point it should be OK.

> Could you send the datasheet by the end of this week?

is more direct as it makes a specific time target. If you have any concern it might not get done, this one is better.

Comment: Thanks @user3169
But don't you think in the following sentence:
"Could you send the datasheet within this week?"
Using "this" sounds a bit redundant?

Comment: @A-friend I think you need the "this". Actually, I consider "within this week" as a set phrase. As I mentioned its not specific on purpose, so you are not pressing for a specific completion date. And the actual date may vary depending on the local calendar, work week, etc. You know what the due date is but you are not stating it specifically. Its more about being specific (or not) rather than being polite. Though some people won't like making a specific commitment, I wouldn't consider that rude.

Comment: @A-friend I would get rid of “within” and “this” and just write “send this week”. “Within” causes the listener to expect a measurement of time reaching out from the present.

Answer (score 0):

Putting *could* takes care of the politeness you are concerned about.

> [could (#3) (v)](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/could) - *used to politely ask somebody to do something for you.*

As far as the sentences are concerned, the first one does not look natural to me. But I'm a non-native speaker.

The second one is better as compared to the first one but then again, whey you are telling someone to do some task by this week, it includes **the weekend**. Because the week ends with a weekend! Who knows, you may get the datasheet earlier than weekend as asked! So...

> Could you send the datasheet by this week?

Comment: Thanks @MaulikV. But as for your sentence I doubt whether it is a correct one! Week refers to a non-specific and a "period" of the time, while "by" is used for a specific spot in the time. Hence, I think you have to paraphrase your sentence ("Could you send the datasheet by this week?") in the following way:
- Could you send the datasheet by "the end of" this week?
Moreover concerning your link I have to that you, but I was well-aware about the usage of the modal "could", and the only problem was bout some particular writings such as a formal letter and the usage of a proper preposition there.

Comment: @A-friend oops, you missed the important word *this*. When you say *by this week* it means sending the datasheet before the new week begins, isn't it? Don't we say *by Saturday* which means **on or before** Saturday. And about *could*, as I said, it automatically takes care of *politeness*. In fact, the definition itself includes this word. You were concerned about the *politeness* and that's the sole reason I mentioned the definition.